# Is C# optimizing overloaded methods called in cascade?

Tags: c#, optimization, overloading

I have some code like that:

```
class MainApplication {

    protected static string _since;

    protected static void updateSince()
    {
        MainApplication.updateSince(DateTime.Now);
    }

    public static void updateSince(DateTime since)
    {
        MainApplication.updateSince(since.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    } 

    public static void updateSince(string since)
    {
        // finally, doing something real
        MainApplication._since = since;
    }

    /* ... */  

}
```

And I wonder if and how C# optimizes such cascade call?

Comment: WHat kind of optimizations did you have in mind? why do you think there would be any optimization? it's just overloaded methods calling each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, C# doesn't optimize stuff at all. What you are asking is, whether the compiler optimizes this...
The compiler doesn't "optimize" this. You can verify this when you have a look at the generated IL code.

Comment: +1 - I mean, what would the compiler optimize? The act of calling `updateSince()` into the overload with now as a string?

Comment: Yes, I think the OP asks, whether the compiler does some kind of inlining.

Comment: Using ILSpy (http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx) shows that the different methods are all called separately.

Comment: Sorry for my lack of precision ;). It's exactly what I was asking.

Comment: I'd assume that he's asking if the JIT would optimize something (not exactly sure what "something" should be here though) here. After all the C# Compiler (actually I'm only certain for javac but I assume it's imilar) does no/only simple optimizations at best.